# Active Directory Log on To... setting keeps resetting Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012

My current work environment consists of a DC running Windows Server 2012. Upon creating new users, or assigning old users to new terminals, they get an error when trying to log into their workstation

> Your account is configured to prevent you from using this computer.

An easy fix to this is going into the account properties of the user in question, and switching the Log On To option to "All Computers". The problem is that this setting keeps flipping back to "The Following Computers" So this problem never fully goes away.

Can someone help me find a permanent fix to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check  `admincount` on the attribute editor tab for an effected user in AD. Is there a 1 next to it?

Comment: Admincount is set to <not set>

Comment: The admincount is set to <not set>

Comment: Ok, how often does it revert back? After a certain amount of time? Just randomly? Anything in the event logs?

Comment: It happens at least once a day with a handful of our users. Nothing comes up in the event logs to my knowledge.

Comment: I would look to see if you have some automated script that changes those settings.

Comment: I don't believe that it's an automated script making the changes - It seems as if the changes flip by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can review the security event log to learn the time and the account making the change in event 4738 with the proper auditing enabled (default domain controllers policy).
There is a older/legacy audit policy that may be in place if you have not yet enabled the Advanced Audit policy.

**Old**
Polices/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Audit Policy
Audit Account Management: Success
Audit Directory Service Access: Success
We have both, I think you only need the first

**Advanced Audit Configuration**
Account Management
Audit User Account Management: Success

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          9/17/2015 3:29:03 PM
Event ID:      4738
Task Category: User Account Management
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      dc99.acme.com
Description:
A user account was changed.

Subject:
    Security ID:        DOM\admin1
    Account Name:       admin1
    Account Domain:     DOM
    Logon ID:       0x1155e950

Target Account:
    Security ID:        DOM\user1
    Account Name:       user1
    Account Domain:     DOM

Changed Attributes:
    SAM Account Name:   -
    Display Name:       -
    User Principal Name:    -
    Home Directory:     -
    Home Drive:     -
    Script Path:        -
    Profile Path:       -
    User Workstations:  barney
    Password Last Set:  -
    Account Expires:        -
    Primary Group ID:   -
    AllowedToDelegateTo:    -
    Old UAC Value:      -
    New UAC Value:      -
    User Account Control:   -
    User Parameters:    -
    SID History:        -
    Logon Hours:        -
```